# Refresh Google Search Results for My Site

Tags: seo

I set up a site with a template and the title was something they supplied as a default.  When I searched for my site's title, it showed up in results, but it was with their default title.  After changing it a couple days ago, my site still shows up with the default title instead of what I changed it to.

Is there any way I can force Google to update their information so the title I have now shows up in results instead of the default title?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on StackOverflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will refresh your website immediately:

1. From Web Master tools Menu -> Crawl -> Fetch as Google
2. Leave URL blank to fetch the homepage then click Fetch
3. Submit to Index button will appear beside the fetched result; click it then choose >  URL and all linked pages > OK

Comment: Link for webmasters: https://www.google.com/webmasters

Comment: Google documentation about it: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but my site still show angular values:
https://www.google.com/#q=npg+cloud

what could i be doing wrong? i followed the steps like you described them

Comment: It seems new version has come. I tried left menu URL inspection, or just click on top "inspect" field and click enter. Then first block right bottom -  REQUEST INDEXING. This worked for me in new version of google search console.

Answer (score 3):

Just wait, Google should normally revisit your site and update its informations. But if you are hurried, you can try the following steps :

- Increase the crawl speed of your site in Google Webmaster Tools : http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48620
- Ping your website on service like http://pingomatic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Submit if you have not yet or resubmit an updated sitemap of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching as Google works, as already suggested. However stage 2 should be - submit your sites to several large social bookmarking sites like digg, reddit, stumbleupon, etc etc. There are huge lists of these sites out there.

Google notices everything on these sites and it will speed up the re crawling process. You can keep track of when Google last cached your site (There is a big difference between crawling and caching) by going to.. cache:sitename.com