# Refresh Google Search Title

Tags: seo

We changed the title and meta description of our home page a few weeks ago. Then we performed the Crawl > Fetch as Google in webmaster tools as outlined ([Refresh Google Search Results for My Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913516/refresh-google-search-results-for-my-site)). Within an hour the description of our page in Google search changed, but the title stayed the same. A few weeks later it’s still the same as the old title. Can anyone explain this behavior and what can I do so Google will display the new title?

Our domain is 4 years old.  DA=29, PA-40

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I found the answer. The difference between my old title and my new title was simply rearranging some words. I made a third title that had more changes and that title was updated in less than an hour. It looks like Google keeps an order independent hash of words in the title, and if only the order changed, Google thinks it's the same title as before and doesn't update it.

Answer (score 0):

Google is not suppose to display the exact title you put in your title tag IF he think this one is not corresponding/relevant enough with the real content of your page.Are you sure your title tag is relevant to your topic and not too spammy or duplicated with another one??? Try to change a little in your content, then again your title then internal link anchors and external link anchir with this new title.

Comment: Thanks.  My old title is {company} : {some title}. The new title is simply: {some title} : {company}. So the relevancy to the keywords should be the same. Is it possible that it just takes longer that 2-3 weeks for Google to update title of a 4-year old domain?